# Render text with SKRenderer

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, metal

I initialized SKRenderer in my project to use it alongside of metal. Although I'm not sure that I did it correctly, I need to know how I can render a simple 2D text with it?

For example, here is how we can draw a text with `SKLabelNode`, do we have anything like it for SKRenderer?
thank you so much

```
let winner = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
winner.text = "You Win!"
winner.fontSize = 65
winner.fontColor = SKColor.red
winner.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
view.addChild(winner)
```

Comment: Please provide your metal render class.

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 Thanks, I added in the first post. Beside this file, I have another file for MetalView and another file to render a specific data to with metal

Comment: Where in your class you initialize `SKLabelNode`?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 I didn't really  initialize SKLabelNode, becuase I was looking for SKRenderer method, but you see the exampe in the first post, I updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is initialize the scene.

```
var renderer: SKRenderer
var skScene: SKScene
```

in your init function:

```
renderer = SKRenderer(device: device)
// iphone 11 portrait
skScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 1125, height: 2436))
renderer.scene = skScene

let winner = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
winner.text = "You Win!"
winner.fontSize = 65
winner.fontColor = SKColor.red
winner.position = CGPoint(x: 1125 / 2, y: 2436 / 2)
skScene.addChild(winner)
```

and finally in your render function:

```
renderer.render(withViewport: viewport, renderCommandEncoder: renderEncoder, renderPassDescriptor: renderPassDescriptor, commandQueue: commandQueue)
renderEncoder.endEncoding()
```

but keep in mind ui layer (**SKRenderer**) should be rendered in the last pass.

Comment: Dear @0xBFE1A8, I can thank you enough for your help. I really appreciate it. You just saved me. Stay safe

Comment: just a question @0xBFE1A8 , is it possible to draw multiple SKLabelNode? because now I am dding a label on the peak of the chart and it works fine, but when there is more than a peak in the screen, it always shows the label on the newest one

Comment: Hi, could you ask this as a new question, and please explain in more detail.

Comment: Thanks @0xBFE1A8  I created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61139117/add-dynamically-sklabelnode-to-mktview