# Add dynamically SKLabelNode to MKTVIew

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, metal, sklabelnode

I am working on metal view that shows the heart rate graph. between every peak of this graph, I need to add a label.

In this process, chart moving from right to left 
I have an array that dynamically shows the x coordinate of this label 
for example when one value should show in the screen, this array contain only element and if there are more, it contain more element, this array is named `coordinates`

I use a for loop to get every element

```
  for coordinate in coordinates {

  }
```

I also have another array that dynamically shows the text of the label, and it works same as `coordinates`.  It's named `rrIntervalData`.

to define this label, I asked another question here: [Render text with SKRenderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61081439/render-text-with-skrenderer)

here is my code

```
skScene.size = CGSize(width: CGFloat(viewportSize.x), height: CGFloat(viewportSize.y))

  for coordinate in coordinates {

     var index = 0
     skLabel.text = "\(rrIntervalData[index].value)"
     skLabel.position = CGPoint(x: Int(coordinate), y: 200)
     skLabel.fontSize = 20
     skLabel.fontColor = SKColor.red
     index += 1

  }
```

`skLabel` is a `SKLabelNode`.
I also have `skScene.addChild(skLabel)`, that I added in the `init` of the parent class (I know this is not correct), If I add it here, the app get crashed because `skLabel` is already added to `skScene`.

In the current version, the label is created in every point, and it moves with graph (as expected), but when the coordinate of the new label comes to screen, the first label is gone and it shows in the second position, and If I zoom out the graph when it should show more than 20 label in a same time, it always show the label in the last label in the right side.

how can I create a dynamic number of labels that set set here and stick with every coordinate and value?

Your help will be appreciated, It has been more than a week that I couldn't deal with adding this label.

Comment: Any help or suggestion?

Comment: Please add a screenshot showing you issue.

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 I fixed that, thank you so much for all of your help

Comment: Please share how you solve that for future similar problems.